# MVVX Failed to initialize ViewModel from MvxDefaultViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I am trying to create a mobile application using MVVX.
get below error when trying to run the Droid application.

MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type ThoughtOfTheDay.ViewModels.LoginViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check InnerException for more information

**Below is the detail of inner exception.**
MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type ThoughtOfTheDay.ViewModels.LoginViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check InnerException for more information ---> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Problem creating viewModel of type LoginViewModel ---> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: **Failed to resolve parameter for parameter messenger of type IMvxMessenger when creating ThoughtOfTheDay.ViewModels.LoginViewModel**
  at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.GetIoCParameterValues (System.Type type, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo firstConstructor) [0x00036] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\IoC\MvxSimpleIoCContainer.cs:504 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x0002a] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\IoC\MvxSimpleIoCContainer.cs:314 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.Mvx.IocConstruct (System.Type t) [0x00005] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\Mvx.cs:170 
  at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.Load (System.Type viewModelType, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle parameterValues, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00000] in <69bce0378e8e413982d3b552d7e387a8>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.Load (System.Type viewModelType, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle parameterValues, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00027] in <69bce0378e8e413982d3b552d7e387a8>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxViewModelLocator viewModelLocator) [0x00015] in <69bce0378e8e413982d3b552d7e387a8>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxViewModelLocator viewModelLocator) [0x00046] in <69bce0378e8e413982d3b552d7e387a8>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00020] in <69bce0378e8e413982d3b552d7e387a8>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.ViewModelFromRequest (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest viewModelRequest, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00005] in :0 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.CreateViewModelFromIntent (Android.Content.Intent intent, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00027] in :0 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.Load (Android.Content.Intent intent, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState, System.Type viewModelTypeHint) [0x00089] in :0 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.LoadViewModel (MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidView androidView, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState) [0x0006a] in :0 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__1 () [0x0000a] in :0 
  at MvvmCross.Core.Views.MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate (MvvmCross.Core.Views.IMvxView view, System.Func`1[TResult] viewModelLoader) [0x00012] in <69bce0378e8e413982d3b552d7e387a8>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.OnViewCreate (MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidView androidView, Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00062] in <f6aebf863dc84be7b380cfec8d459508>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityAdapter.EventSourceOnCreateCalled (System.Object sender, MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1[T] eventArgs) [0x0000c] in :0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1[MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1[Android.OS.Bundle]]:invoke_void_object_TEventArgs (object,MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1<Android.OS.Bundle>)
  at MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.Raise[T] (System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs] eventHandler, System.Object sender, T value) [0x00000] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\Core\MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.cs:21 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.Droid.Views.MvxEventSourceActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00014] in <4230cf00b647458f9b3e211590e6cc9d>:0 
  at ThoughtOfTheDay.Droid.Views.LoginView.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00002] in C:\Work\MobileDev\ThoughtOfTheDay\ThoughtOfTheDay\ThoughtOfTheDay.Droid\Views\LoginView.cs:15

**I am trying to pass IMvxMessenger to the view model. Inner exception message above shows there is a problem resolving IMvxMessenger. Do I need to include something for it in the app.cs\Initialize() ? Let me know if you need more info. Thanks a lot for your time and help.**

```
public LoginViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger,
            IDialogService dialogService,
            IUserService userService)
            : base(messenger)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            _dialogService = dialogService;
        }
```

[image]

**Solution: Installed Nuget package for MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger in the Android project as well.
Earlier I had it installed only in the PCL project.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution: Installed Nuget package for MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger in the Android project as well. Earlier I had it installed only in the PCL project.**

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are missing the bootstrap for the plugin.

Make sure a class inside of the Bootstrap folder has been made with the following contents:

```
using MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins;

namespace your.name.space.Bootstrap
{
    public class MessengerPluginBootstrap
        : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.PluginLoader>
    {
    }
}
```

This will register the plugin with the IoC container.

Alternatively you can register it yourself in `InitializeLastChance` in your `Setup.cs` file:

```
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxMessenger>(() => new MvxMessengerHub());
```

Comment: Thanks Cheesebaron, i already did that, in my case solution was as listed above at the end in my question.

Comment: Ah right. Didn't see that. What installing the plugin in the platform specific project does, is to actually create that bootstrap file, but also allow using the plugin on that platform. Most plugins require you to install it in the platform specific project anyways. Either way. Add your own answer and accept it :)

Comment: Thanks for the info mate :)